# d3 - How to identify the bottom part of a bar in a horizontal barchart

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart

Ok, so I need to build several barcharts that have in between the first bar and the others a yellow line.

```
var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, height], .2);
```

...

```
svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "bar " + d.label; })
    .attr("id", function(d){return d.label})
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(Math.min(0, d.value)); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.label); })
    .attr("width", function(d) { return Math.abs(x(d.value) - x(0)); })
    .attr("height", y.rangeBand());
```

and this is where I'm trying to build the yellow line:

```
svg.append("line")
  .attr("class", "yellow")
  .attr("x1", 0 )
  .attr("x2", width )
  .attr("y1", y.rangeBand() + 14)
  .attr("y2", y.rangeBand()+14);
```

So, this way the line is more or less in the position I need, but if the number of bar changes (and it happens) and consequently the height of the bar change, it obviously go out of position and end up behind the bar.

Any idea on how to find the value?

Comment: I may be missing something here, but isn't `y.rangeBand()` going to give you that value?

Comment: I thought so, as well... but with just that the line appears almost in the middle of the first bar...

Comment: Ok, you may have to adjust the offset -- my point is that the position should be consistent even if the number of bars changes?

Comment: yes, and if I add a fixed px value that's not keeping the bar consistently in between the first and the second bar

Comment: Update! This is closer: .attr("y2", y.rangeBand()+ y(0)); the line gets attached to the bottom of the first bar. What I'm searching is to have the line in between the first and the second bar... How do i know what the padding is between one bar and the other?

Comment: I think for `rangeRoundBands` you need to do `2 * y.rangeBand()`.

Comment: nope, that makes the line go straight in the middle of the second bar...

Comment: So what about `y.rangeBand() * 1.5`?

Comment: That depending on the number of bars in the chart it goes more up or more down, but more or less is in place. It is also only working if the barchart is showing a table with one column of values, if it's two columns it will have to be a *3 and if it's 3 columns it will have to be *4.5...

Comment: Could you put the complete code somewhere, preferably on jsfiddle?